# Ruby on Rails Best Practices For Third Party Integration Code Placement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked at other SO postings and some blog postings on where it's best to place third party integration code but naturally, there's a plethora of opinions and answers so was hoping to get a more definitive answer with my scenario.

Here's a quick breakdown of my user story:

**When a User is on their profile page, they have the ability to ask for a refresh of their Twitter and / or Facebook info.**

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :twitter_account
  has_one :facebook_account
end

class TwitterAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class FacebookAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**What I'm looking for:** 
When the User wants to update their twitter account info, I want to be able to call some method that returns to me the fetched account info. Somewhere that handles all the Auth, Fetching, Posting, and Parsing of the JSON Response. I want to keep this logic outside of the model because it's just going to get cluttered and those methods really behave a little outside of the norm MVC of my app.

The current implementation I've been going with is making separate classes in `/lib` for each the Integration Entities. So `/lib/twitter_api` and `/lib/facebook_api`. In here is where I keep all the connections (GETs, POSTs) and the extracting of data I want from the responses.

Maybe this direction is the way to go for me but I just wanted some feedback before I got too far into it.

**Using Ruby 2.1.1 & Rails 4.1.1**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if I can speak to a "best practice", but here is how I approach third party integration.

I'm biased against using `/lib` for [very much](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/).
If code is directly relevant to my running application, then I want it in `/app`. If code is relevant to my application and other applications, then I want it in a gem. Generally, what remains in `/lib` is code that is trivially easy or hasn't been made into a gem yet. For example, if I'm still determining the structure of the code, I find it easier to do that from `/lib` than a gem. I avoid referencing items in `/app` from `/lib`.

My first concern is to get external API calls outside of the main request/response flow. I don't want poor response time from an external service to reflect poorly on my application. In Rails, this means I wouldn't have an API call to a third party service within a controller action. Instead, my controller immediately register their request as a background job to process later and then inform them that it will be processed.

I place the code for my background jobs in `app/jobs`. I haven't integrated with Twitter and
Facebook, but I suspect there are gems that handle the majority of the connection and data retrieval. The job code would retrieve the data using those gems, transform the code, and then update the ActiveRecord models.

I consider data transformation to be part of my domain model. I would create a directory under `/app/models` for that code so that it is clearly separated from the ActiveRecord models. The job would reference this code to perform the transformation.

---

I'm sure `/lib/twitter_api` and `lib/facebook_api` will work as well. As much as I avoid `/lib`, I do like that you're restricting those items to their own directories so that they are cohesive in that regard.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks! I am using resque for the actual fetching so the user doesn't have poor response time. My issue has been deciding on whether these services really are first class citizens of my app or not and I've decided they are so I think I'm moving them out of lib.